# Capture elements from beginning of flux and create a new flux that contains both captured elements and remaining elements

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm working with a spring cloud gateway based project and my goal is to capture and log incoming and outgoing messages partially. Request logging must be done before request is passed to backend service and same policy applies to response. Implementation should be based on a filter. I have no control over when gateway subscribes to resulting flux.

In short, I would like to do following:

1. Capture up to x bytes of data from flux
2. Log captured data
3. Create a flux that contains both captured data and remaining data

So far I got this - and it seems to be working. I'd just like to know, if I missed something and/or if there's a better way to implement this. I'm sure someone else has been struggling with a similar problem:

```
Flux<Integer> body = Flux.range(1, 50).log(); // Simulate flow of data
ConnectableFlux<Integer> sharedBody = body.publish(1); // Content is already buffered - ideal prefetch would be 0
AtomicLong readCount = new AtomicLong(); // Counter
AtomicReference<Flux<Integer>> partiallyCachedFlux = new AtomicReference<>(); // A hack, not to be used in real world

Flux.from(sharedBody)
    .takeUntil(s -> {
        System.out.println("C:" + s);
        return readCount.incrementAndGet() >= 10; // Store up to 10 elements
    })
    .collectList()
    .subscribe(ints -> {
        System.out.println("Collected:" + ints); // Log what we got
        partiallyCachedFlux.set(
                Flux.concat(Flux.fromIterable(ints).log(), sharedBody)
                ); // Create a flux that contains captured data and remaining data
    });
sharedBody.connect();

Thread.sleep(1000); // Because I was lazy

partiallyCachedFlux.get()
    .doOnEach(i -> { if (i.isOnNext()) System.out.println("P:" + i.get());})
    .subscribe(); // Show that we have captured everything
```

Comment: This solution just failed badly when I started testing it thoroughly. One of problematic area was handling errors. Another major issue was that I was able to get deadlocks in my tests - which is never a good sign.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of `takeUntil` is `skipUntil`. You could `share` the original flux into 2 flux, one of which takesUntil and the other skipsUntil. Your end result would simply be the `Flux.merge` of both flux.

Note that when externalizing state like this (`AtomicInteger`), you'll run into problems if the whole `Flux` is subscribed to multiple times. The way to work around that is to wrap everything into a `Flux.defer`, so that the external state is created within the lambda and thus specific to a given subscription.

Comment: Flux is backed by a single tcp connection, so I don't think it can be subscribed multiple times.

If I did split flux created using publish to two fluxes, where would I subscribe to flux that has skipUntil. If first flux is closed before I do second subscription (which should be done by spring framework), flux created with publish() will be disconnected.

Comment: maybe connectableFlux.refCnt(2) rather than share. the merge would subscribe to the two shared versions of the Flux, and spring would subscribe to the merged Flux, triggering the whole thing

Comment: Requirement was: Request logging must be done before request is passed to backend service.

If both parties subscribe at same time, then it data will start flowing to backend. This is what I want to avoid. We need to write the entry before we can allow data to flow. 

Now I do know that original solution doesn't work, but the one that works has been tested extensively with load testing and it has also been verified to handle corner cases properly. It seems ok from performance perspective, but it's just too ugly to be published

I think I need processors, but don't have time to learn them